# WLAN: Domestic Router only handling up to 15 clients

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router

I guess this could be a problem concerning: processor, memory or bandwidth.

I have a TL WR841nd router, and I need to connect 35 tablets into it via Wireless. Just WLAN! no Internet.
However, the router only handles 15 tablets.

The 16th's one tells "Wireless saved" as it understands the wifi password is correct but the router won't give it an IP address. The DHCP is set to handle 100 clients.

What can I do? I was about to install OpenWRT or DD-WRT to monitor a bit better what's happening.

Comment: Is it possible that DHCP is configured to only provide IP addresses for 15 clients? Do the device logs show anything that could help?  AS a side note, 35 clients sharing that WiFi connection could be challenging depending on what the client devices are being used for.

Comment: I forgot to mention. DHCP is configured to provide 100 clients. I'll enable logs

Comment: Do you have the latest firmware on the router?

Comment: I should check, but it is brand-new. It should came with almost the lastest one.

Comment: Devices often come with an older firmware and then upgrades provide added features/bug fixes, etc  Check the vendor site http://www.tp-link.com/lk/products/details/?model=TL-WR841ND#down for updates

Comment: The router log might shed some light on the issue. On my TP-Link router, I can read the log at `System Tools > System Log`

Comment: Version 9 of software has this comment -Improved the numbers of maximum wireless clients to 31

Answer (score 1):

Note that some versions of the software for this model router limited WiFi clients.  On Version 9 devices firmware TL-WR841ND_V9_141013 increases wireless clients to 31

From the [TP Link Firmware revision log for TL-WR841ND:](http://www.tp-link.com/lk/support/download/?model=TL-WR841ND&version=V9#tbl_j)

> Improved the numbers of maximum wireless clients to 31;

Comment: It should be that. After upgrading I'll confirm it. That answers my question, but: I need to connect 35 devices, maybe 37. Do you think OpenWRT or DD-WRT firmwares would push it to bigger limits? I'm starting reading about it.

Comment: @redraw Your router model (firmware versions 3.x, 5.x, 7.x and 8.x) is supported by DD-WRT so you could experiment and find out. You can always revert back to stock firmware if it doesn't work out.

Comment: That's right. Mine is v9, but I found there is a DD-WRT version in the BrainSlayer repository here, http://dd-wrt.com/site/support/other-downloads?path=others%2Feko%2FBrainSlayer-V24-preSP2%2F

Comment: OpenWrt is up to v7, http://downloads.openwrt.org/barrier_breaker/14.07/ar71xx/generic/

Comment: I still wonder if I would be pushing it to its hardware limits, rather than firmware ones.